# How to read the -Dserver.ref VM argument

Tags: java, tomcat, junit, mockito

Tomcat is started with a vm argument: `-Dserver.ref=test`. The value of this argument determines what type of properties file is to be read by the application. Unit tests also depend on the value of this property and need to match what is set in Tomcat.

I think I just need to set this property myself within the unit test ? I don't think there a mechanism to check what the value `-Dserver.ref` is within Tomcat ?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
final String ref = System.getProperty("server.ref");
```

`ref` should be equal to `"test"`.

Comment: that assumes the test is running within same JVM ?

Comment: @user701254: you want to read this flag from another JVM? If so, try with `jmap` or connect to that JVM via JMX. If you are interested, I'll find some code samples.

Answer (score 4):

You should put the code that reads the system property in a separate class like RealSystemPropertyReader that implements an interface SystemPropertyReader. The default implementation of the class would read the property using System.getProperty(). A mock version of your class MockSystemPropertyReader would be used in unit tests and would return whatever you tell it to return.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer.  A test that depends on a REAL system property is not a unit test.